Why my remote view in notification is not displaying correctly in some device?
this is i am expecting and i have achieved this but,

this happens in some device when i try to use remote view.

i am making otp reader application, so when a new otp sms received i am showing this custom view notification.
            int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_view);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), new Intent(NOTIFICATION_CLICK), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
            PendingIntent copyIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), new Intent(NOTIFICATION_COPY), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
            PendingIntent deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), new Intent(NOTIFICATION_DELETE), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

            notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnCopy, copyIntent);
            notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnDelete, deleteIntent);


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel channel = manager.getNotificationChannel(String.valueOf(id));
                if (channel == null) {
                    channel = new NotificationChannel(String.valueOf(id), "Channel Title", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                    //config nofication channel
                    channel.setDescription("[Channel description]");
                    channel.enableVibration(true);
                    channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 1000, 200, 340});
                    channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                }
            }

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, String.valueOf(id)).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setContentTitle("Title").setContentText("Your text description").setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setCustomContentView(notificationView)
                    .setOngoing(false)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 1000, 200, 340}).setAutoCancel(false)//true touch on notificaiton menu dismissed, but swipe to dismiss

                    .setTicker("Nofiication");
            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            NotificationManagerCompat m = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
            //id to generate new notification in list notifications menu
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            m.notify(new Random().nextInt(), builder.build());

currently i am using this code to show to my custom notification but it doesn't working in some device as expected.
what shoould i do so that this notification custom view would look perfectly in every device.

Can you share more info on "doesn't working in some device"?  Is there something specific to this "some device", like the OS-version, or android version?

Yes it cloud be but i have tested in vivo Android 12 device and oppo Android 12 but the problem is showing in only vivo but not in oppo device whereas both have same Android version.
